# Best way to render organisation data using jQuery Tree

Tags: jquery, tree

I am kinda stuck with my design layout on how to render data. The situation is something as follows:

*There are various departments with different employees working under each of them. Now each department can have child departments under it with employees working in the child departments.*

I need to display this entire layout on a html page preferably using a jQuery tree or something. I am thinking something like a tree structure with departments displayed in a hierarchical format like follows:

```
Dept A
 - Dept A.1
   - Dept A.1.1
   - Dept A.1.2
 - Dept A.2
   - Dept A.2.1
     - Dept A.2.1.1
```

Now I also need to display employees under each department and kinda provide a drag-from-one-department-to-another feature. This is where I am stuck with the design as to how it can be depicted in a proper way in the html page.

Could someone please help me out on this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

create an object Dept in Javascript , that holds an array of names and an array of children Dept and insert an object into an object whenever needed , then you can traverse that object till there is nothing to traverse.

Comment: From the technical perspective, I am okay with whatever needs to be done. What I am confused is about the layout, like what would be the best way to display all these info on the screen and also be able to provide all features. Like where exactly I can display the employees.